# Proper raised heel fastening?

Tags: framing, attic

I recently noticed that instead of hurricane ties or gusset plate, my rafters are fastened to the joists with 2x4 and 16d nails. Is this an accepted method to secure the rafters? Its a gable roof, 1300sq ft, attic has ridge beam, collar ties and purlins if that matters. Pictures below. [image]
[image]

Comment: The 2x4s are only good against uplift, so those toe nails attaching the rafters to the joists don't inspire confidence by sticking out like that. Without knowing the design wind pressures and rafter lengths, it's impossible to say yea or nay on the adequacy of the uplift detail. It could be fine.

Comment: And by purlins, you mean purlins under the rafters? Is there a load path down from them that can resist uplift also?

Comment: Correct, purlins along the bottom third of the rafters. They do have bracing tied into the ceiling joists about every third rafter.

Comment: The 2x4s are good for about 380# of uplift each (assuming 16d common nails), for what it's worth. For comparison there's a load table under https://www.strongtie.com/seismicandhurricaneties_strapsandties/h8_htie/p/h8. The 380# is for comparison against their SPF/HF uplift, where that "(160)" is for a 1.60 load duration factor that has also been applied to arrive at the 380#.

Comment: But are the ceiling joists tied down effectively? The roof can leave as a unit if they are not (happened *after* a friend moved out of that particular apartment building, thankfully.)

Comment: Are there a bunch of blown toe nails between the rafters and the joists? In my area with our non-trivial snow loads, I would be fixing that connection. But with your purlins, maybe your joists don't function as rafter ties? Maybe you've got a structural ridge beam and therefore don't need rafter ties? I would just assume that the blown nails were structurally important and correctly install a matching nail for each bad one.

Comment: When you say blown, I’m answering as if you meant they completely missed a solid portion of the joists. Which they seem to mostly have connected within about 1” of the seam. If I misunderstood the question, apologies. As far as I can tell, the ridge beam is not structural. No robust vertical framing at either terminating end of the board, just typical studs and horizontal bracing across them. I would guess that the purlins would satisfy the definition of a rafter tie(?)- being lower 1/3rd horizontal reinforcement, themselves tied into the ceiling joists. Thanks for the input